# How will the seats be allocated if I don't reserve one before?

Tags: air-travel, india, bookings, domestic-travel, spicejet

I booked two seats for one way flight. The ticket doesn't have seat number yet so I am allowed to select any available seats for a fee usually 2 to 5 USD for a seat. What if I don't select the seats? How will they be allocated? Is it random? I booked via an online travel agency.

Company is spicejet airline.

Comment: It also depends on which seats that others paying 2 to 5 USD select, so it is impossible to predict.

Comment: It's safe to say that if other people have the option to choose seats, they'll choose the best ones available (e.g., aisle or window seat, near the front, etc.) You'll get what's left.

Comment: @newguy Have you tried searching spicejet’s terms & conditions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They will assign seats randomly, if you checkin online.

What I usually do is, do not check-in online and go bit early, ask in counter nicely that I prefer a window seat. I always gets the window seat, when asked. I traveled in spicejet and same was the case.

Answer (score 3):

They will be randomly distributed at online check-in.

Note that if you want to sit together, you can always ask someone in the plane to switch. Unless you got both middle seats...not many people would switch an aisle or window seat to sit in a middle seat. Or you pay to pick your seats.

Answer (score 0):

Largely depends on the airline. If there are two of you, most airlines will seat you together after online check-in however some will seat you apart to try and force you to pay for better seats.

Comment: Doesn't really help, since the author has specified their airline. Would be better if it were tailored to that.

Comment: It's unlikely the airline's algorithm deliberately tries to break up parties. What does happen is that the windows and aisles fill up first, so when remaining seats are assigned on the day of departure, all that is left are single middle seats, necessitating groups be separated.